# How do hit points work?

Tags: dnd-4e, new-players

I'm about to start my first D&D game, and I just noticed that my character sheet has four different hit point values. I assume maximum is how many you have before you're dead, but how do `Bloodied`, `Surge value` and `Surges/Day` work?

Comment: Isn't this in the rulebook?

Comment: @YogoZuno Being in the rulebook doesn't mean he can't ask the question.

Comment: I guess that I was pointing out that the rulebook was a much quicker avenue for a response than posting on the internet...not to mention the two closed basic questions from the same person.

Answer (score 19):

OK, you have four different values. Here are their definitions:

- Total HP Value. This is your total hit points. This is defined by your class HP value plus your Con score. When you run out of HP you are *dying*. This is a special condition that is well defined (you are unconscious and begin making saving throws to either wake up or permanantly die).
- Bloodied Value. This is one half your hit points. At this point you are half dead. A number of characters and monsters have abilities that are triggered by or depend on "being bloodied" or attacking a "bloodied" creature. This means a character that is at or below half their HP. When you reach negative your bloodied value in HP (even if you have death saving throws remaining) you die.
- Number of Surges. This is the number of surges that your character has per day. This is defined by your class *surge number* value  plus your Con mod.
- Surge Value. This is 1/4 your hit points. It is used for many healing effects; you "spend a surge" and (usually) gain the number of HP indicated by your surge value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Might be worth adding that some characters and some creatures will have powers and effects that trigger off of the "bloodied" condition

Comment: yes, was going ot mention that. will do,

Comment: Also when you reach 0 you aren't dead, you are dying. You only die if you fail 3 death saving throws or reach -bloodied hit points.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Surge value is defined as 1/4 of max HP, not 1/2 bloodied value. From the Compendium under Healing Surge: _When you spend a healing surge, you regain one-quarter of your maximum hit points (rounded down)._

Answer (score 6):

- *Maximum hit points* are the total amount of hit points you have, and the value you heal up to whenever you take an extended rest.
- The *bloodied value* is simply half of your maximum hitpoints. Bloodied is a condition. Some powers and effects work on or are triggered by the bloodied condition.
- Your *healing surge value* is half of your bloodied value or 1/4th of your maximum hp. Whenever an effect or power allows you to spend a healing surge, you can heal the surge value in hit points. Some leader powers allow you to gain additional healing when spending a healing surge.
- Based on your constitution, your class, level and other things, you get a *number of healing surges* per day. You can spend them using a power such as your second wind, a leader healing power or certain items. Whenever you take an extended rest, you regain all of your healing surges.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a new player to d&d. Hit points are pretty easy when you get the hang of it. For instance a ranger class says 12+constitution score that is your final hit point result. The bloodied section is half of that. Healing surges can be found on page 293 of the phb1, it basically defines how many hit points you can revive for specifics go to your class and it will tell you how many you can start of with.

Remember as you progress in levels you gain extra hit points :)