# Do PCs know about spell levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was reading some lore from the Forgotten Realms and saw something about higher level spell slots (10, 11 and 12) and them being sealed off for mortal beings.

So I was wondering if PCs know about spell levels as we know them, being able to sort them into tables based on spell level, knowing a *fireball* is a level 3 spell and *magic missile* a level 1.

I'm asking this because I want to make a character that is obsessed with 9+ level spells. But this would kinda fall flat without them being able to know the difference between a level 9 and level 10 spell.

Comment: Related: [What is a spell slot in-lore, and how does it justify the limits on casting spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131551/35259)

Comment: Where did you read about higher spell levels? The Forgotten Realms wiki? SCAG?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I did not know there where 9+ level spells in older editions (I only play 5e atm), but i found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/8w1syd/10th_11th_and_12th_level_spells/) reddit post and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiGBXhpQAUg) youtube video about them.

Comment: If you go to the 3.5 SRD and look, under epic level spells.  that's one version of spells above 9th level.  I think the reddit is referring to some Arcane Age material from 2e ... but my memory isn't working well today.